# Grunt task + Ruby script cannot get stdout printed

Tags: ruby, node.js, gruntjs

im trying to make simple grunt task that invokes one ruby script but i cant get any output from nodejs child_process.exec command. Right now im trying to just get contents of "ls -la" command but when i run my task, i get nothing.

Task:

```
'use strict';

var which = require('which'),
    cp = require('child_process'),
    sys = require('sys');

module.exports = function (grunt) {

    var log = grunt.log;

    grunt.registerMultiTask('testtask', 'The best Grunt plugin ever.', function () {

        var command = 'ls -la'; // ruby script.rb
        var args = [
            "test"
        ];

        var childProcess = cp.exec(command, args, function() {});

        log.write("Test log");

        childProcess.stdout.on('data', function (d) { log.write(d); });
        childProcess.stderr.on('data', function (d) { log.error(d); });

    });
};
```

Grunt configuration of task is silly:

```
testtask: {
    options: {
          // Task-specific options go here.
    },
    testtarget: {
        // Target-specific file lists and/or options go here.
    }
  }
```

When i run grunt task i get such an output:

```
Running "hockeyapp:Android" (hockeyapp) task
Test log
Done, without errors.
```

I guess i should see output of "ls" command right? What am I missing?

---

**SOLUTION:**

The problem was that i didn't use async grunt task mechanism propertly. Basically is should look something like this:

```
    grunt.registerMultiTask('testtask', 'The best Grunt plugin ever.', function () {

        var command = 'ls -la'; // ruby script.rb
        var args = [
            "test"
        ];

        var done = this.async();
        cp.exec(command, args, function(error, stdout, stderr) {
          if(error === null) {
            grunt.log.write(stdout);
            done();
          } else {
            grunt.log.error(stderr);
            done(false);
          }
       });


    });
```